# Interpretation of the coin toss code in C

Tags: c, srand, coin-flipping

During classes the teacher presented the C code for simulation of the coin toss. I know that there have been answered many questions about this topic, however, none of them relates strictly to my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TOSS 50

int randof(int n) {
    return rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * n;
}

int main(void) {
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < TOSS; ++i) {
        printf("%d", randof(2));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the part I don't understand:

```
return rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * n;
```

As I have printed out, the results are only 01010101111... for each of the tosses. However, while comparing values of `rand()` and `(RAND_MAX + 1.0) * n` (I have changed the code to:)

```
int r = rand();
printf("|%d %d ", r, RAND_MAX);
return r / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * n;
```

the value of  `r / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * n;` is less than 0,5 for the examples I have checked, thus **I don't understand how it is rounded to 0 or 1.**

Comment: what exactly is your question here? are you asking how the result of `r / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * n`, which is a floating point value, being "rounded" to an integer value? or are you asking something about how random generators work?

Comment: "the value of r / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * n; is less than 0,5". Lets simplify with a low RAND_MAX, say 9.   3/(10.0) * 2 = 0.6  and   2/(10.0) * 2 = 0.4  and 4/(10.0) * 2 = 0.8. I think you must have made a mistake when printing or analysing your examples. Please double check and make a [mre] with the values we can discuss, by using `srand(0u);` to make them reproducable.

Comment: I used `double r =  rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * n;
    printf("\n%lf:", r);
    return r;` and got `1.680375:1
0.788766:0
1.566198:1
1.596880:1
1.823295:1
0.395103:0
0.670446:0
1.536459:1
0.555549:0
1.107940:1
0.954794:0
1.257742:1
0.729569:0
1.026802:1`. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: "is less than 0,5 for the examples I have checked" Check the other values. You can add prints for `r` and `r / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * n` (as double) to see the results

Comment: You are just smoothing the random values. If `r < (RAND_MAX + 1.0) / 2` your output is `0`, otherwise it is `1`.  Think of it this way `r / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)` then times `2`. Why? Including `1.0` instead of `1` forces the intermediate calculation to be done as *floating-point*. You are either multiplying something less than 1/2 by `2` resulting in `0` or multiplying something greater than 1/2 by `2` resulting in something greater than `1` that is truncated to `int` on return.

Comment: If my question came out tobe such a silly problem, do I have to delete it? Thank @Yunnosch for pointing out my mistake and @DavidC.Rankin for his explanation. I think that multiplying by `2` provides the appriopriate probability for this problem (1/2)/.

Comment: Please create an answer instead of editing the solution into the question. Then it will be a decent Q/A pair. (And you should undo the edit which added the answer to the question.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Yunnosch, who pointed out my mistake, I realized that I had seen:

```
r / ((RAND_MAX + 1.0) * n)
```

instead of:

```
(r / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)) * n
```

Thank you for identifying my confusion!

Comment: Finding a "silly" (by your own words) mistake, finding out its details yourself and clearly and helpfully explaining it here is a good thing. You made a good Q/A of it.